# Android BLE GATT protocol service and characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am studying and developing the central side of the BLE with peripheral GATT communication.

At this time, when sending a message from Central to peripheral using GATT communication

```
enter code here
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
        Log.i("onServicesDiscovered",gatt.toString()+"//"+status)

        when (status) {
            BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED)
                val services = gatt.services
                for (service in services) {
                    val characteristics = service.characteristics
                        Log.i("Services",service.toString())
                    for (characteristic in characteristics) {

                        gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
                        Log.i("characteristic", characteristic.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> Log.w("message", "onServicesDiscovered received: $status")
        }
    }
```

I know as i have to using this callback function

Why am i searching for Characteristic and Service used in this function while looking at them all?

Basically, I understand that Characteristic and Service are the units of function.

If you download the app on the peripheral side and receive the message

It was printed only once in the for statement that rotated 6 times in total.

When I connect with GATT connect, a total of 3 Service and 6 Characteristic comes out, and it turns the for statement 6 times.

First of all, I don't know why 3 services are connected... I guess It's a mobile phone, so it's basically included

And I don't know why the medium of communication is this Characteristic

this is my Log

[LogImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNiNy.png)

sorry for this image... I dont know how to upload my log

Comment: Could you post your log output of onServicesDiscovered?

Comment: Hello my friend
I edit my post !

Comment: What peripheral device are you using? Have you tried scanning for it through another app like nRF Connect?

Comment: I use a samsung galaxy mobile phone and app name is 'BLE Peripheral tool'. I also use nRFConnect too . then nrf Connects logs are different from BLE Peripherial tool

Comment: Mobile phone has a basic Service ? which is unchangeable?

Comment: So your mobile phone is your peripheral? You need to use nRF Connect from another phone and scan your peripheral. Maybe 'BLE peripheral tool' does something weird

Comment: nrfConnect app can response my message?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that. The nRF Connect app can scan for BLE devices and display their services, just like your ESP. I want you to see if the nRF app also finds 3 services

Comment: nrf app's services are small difference with other apps, but I found a android mobile phone has two GATT service in their basic function. So BLE peripheral app has a one specific service

Comment: when i connect with android phone with no app opened then i found 2 basic services

Comment: What are these services? You can search for their UUID, maybe you find some info. These characteristics have to come from some kind of app, my android phone does not advertise anything

Comment: But all that does not matter for your problem. After you finished discovering the services of the peripheral you simply access just the characteristics you need, don't worry about the others

Comment: so It doesn't matter writeCharacteristic run 6times in "for loop" ? But how the device know which is the characteristics i need ?

Comment: It does matter. You should only write to the characteristic you want. I assumed you know your peripheral and its characteristics. You could check the UUID of the characteristic and write only to one

Comment: Thank you. then i have to find characteristic UUID first and then fix it in a code . Is it right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to get an automatic connection without user input you need to know what characteristic to write to.